# Column extracted from DataFrame has a different index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm encountering the following situation:

```
some_df.index                 #=> Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
some_df['some_column'].index  #=> Float64Index([7.0, 5.0], dtype='object')
```

Why is this happening?  Does this mean there was something wrong in the way `some_df` was constructed?  Finally, what's the best way to ensure that columns I extract from `some_df` all use the same index as `some_df` itself?

EDIT: I dove deeper into the code and apparently there's a line that simply reassigns the index: `some_df['some_column].index = some_df['another_column']`. How broken is this?

Comment: Please post raw data, code, pandas, numpy and python version, thanks

Comment: @EdChum: I dove into the code and apparently there's a line that simply reassigns the index: `some_df['some_column] = some_series`. How broken is this?

Comment: Sorry I'm assuming this is *your* code as opposed to some bug in pandas?

Comment: @EdChum: yup, it is 3rd party code doing this reassignment, not pandas code. I'm just wondering how correct it is, how likely it is to cause problems, etc.

Comment: Well it depends, I tried assigning a series which had a float index to a df column which had an int index and the index remained untouched, you still need to post raw input data and minimum code and library versions, otherwise no one can verify that they are seeing the same as what you're seeing

Comment: @EdChum: thanks, I was mostly looking for design-level advice - whether reassigning indices on columns in a `DataFrame` is an anti-pattern that must be avoided. I think you thought I was looking for a bug in Pandas, or whether this behavior can cause a bug.

Comment: But what you posted was assignment to a column with another column/series this should not overwrite the index, if you overwrite the index that still should not cause a problem but you're not showing this in your code snippets

Comment: @EdChum: woops!  See correction, it's `some_df['some_column].index = some_df['another_column']`, i.e. reassignment of the index, not the entire series. I can't edit my comment since that time window has elapsed.

Comment: Well that does nothing on pandas `0.16.0`, but `some_df.index = some_df[''another_column']` will overwrite it

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether this is a bug, though perhaps assigning to the Series index should raise (it may be quite tricky to get this behaviour)... You should definitely not be doing this!

To confirm that this is indeed the case:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: df['A'].index
Out[13]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

In [14]: df['A'].index = [7., 8.]

In [15]: df['A'].index
Out[15]: Float64Index([7.0, 8.0], dtype='float64')

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

So whilst this is apparently valid, you're going to get some surprising (potentially undefined) behaviour...

For example:

```
In [21]: df.groupby("A").sum()
Out[21]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [B]
Index: []
```